# Allow multiple emails per account

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, email

It would be good to allow a user to have multiple email addresses per account, like it's done in GitHub and LinkedIn.

I was updating our company information and wanted to invite all developers to "join" the company page to have their avatars shown. They only way to invite devs is through email and now I have to find all their personal email addresses. It's easier to ask them to add their work email address to profile and invite them. This way if they decide to move on, they can just delete their work email address from profile and not have to change anything else.

Users would select one of the email addresses as primary for communication purposes.

I'm not sure if linking multiple login providers like Google, FB, etc would do the same trick already.

Ref:
https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-email-address-to-your-github-account/
https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/60

Comment: I'm confused... I *have* two emails attached to my account...

Comment: I'm also confused. Is this talking about some Careers feature?

Comment: This feature already exists via multiple login providers, it's just not very clear.

Answer (score 4):

I checked and it you can easily have multiple emails by adding multiple Google logins and other such accounts. It's just not that obvious. In Facebook you have one account and can add lots of emails to it. Here you have to add multiple login accounts to add more email addresses.

[image: Screenshot of account settings screen with multiple logins]